# Как удалить формы с указанными id в javascript

Tags: javascript, queryselector

Пытаюсь "удалить" формы с помощью нижеприведённого кода, но не выходит. Из всех убирается тогда форма с id subdivisionForm. Все айдишники проставлены верно

```js
window.onload = function () {
            let subdivisionForm = document.querySelector('#subdivisionForm');
            let generalForm = document.querySelector('#generalForm');
            let loginShare = document.querySelector('#loginShare');
            let passForm = document.querySelector('#passForm');

            if (typeof subdivisionForm !== 'undefined' || typeof generalForm !== 'undefined' || typeof loginShare !== 'undefined' || typeof passForm !== 'undefined'){
                subdivisionForm.innerHTML = "";
                generalForm.innerHTML = "";
                loginShare.innerHTML = "";
                passForm.innerHTML = "";
            }
        }
```

```html
<form id='generalForm' method='post' action='". $url ."'>
        <input type='password' name='enterPassword' placeholder='Введите пароль от файла'>
        <input type='submit' name='sendPassword' value='Подтвердить'>
    </form>

    <form method='post' action='$url' id='subdivisionForm'>
        <input hidden name='shareChoose' value='$shareChoose'>
        <input hidden name='sharePath' value='$path'>
        <input hidden name='shareFilename' value='$filename'>
        <input type='submit' name='shareSubdivision' value='Поделиться'>
    </form>

    <form method='post' action='$url' id='loginShare'>
        <input hidden name='shareChoose' value='$shareChoose'>
        <input hidden name='sharePath' value='$path'>
        <input hidden name='shareFilename' value='$filename'>
        <input type='text' name='loginForShare' placeholder='Введите логин пользователя'>
        <input type='submit' name='shareLogin' value='Поделиться'>
    </form>

    <form method='post' action='$url' id='passForm'> 
        <input hidden name='shareChoose' value='$shareChoose'> 
        <input hidden name='sharePath' value='$path'> 
        <input hidden name='shareFilename' value='$filename'> 
        <input type='text' name='pass' placeholder='Введите пароль для скачивания'> 
        <input type='submit' name='shareGeneral' value='Поделиться'> 
    </form>
```

Comment: покажи html, что и как там

Comment: Кстати, `querySelector()` при отсутствии элемента возвращает `null`, поэтому ваше условие со строгим сравнением будет всегда срабатывать.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myForm = document.forms.myForm

myForm.removeMe.addEventListener('click', () => {
    myForm.remove()
})
```

```html
<form  name="myForm">
    form here
    <button name="removeMe">remove</button>
</form>
```

можно как-то так, если действительно хочешь удалить форму, а не сбросить

Comment: Я бы хотел сделать так, чтобы они удалялись именно при загрузке страницы, а не по кнопке

Comment: ну смысл понятен, как удалять ? подпилить под себя - и все будет

Answer (score 0):

```js
const forms = [...document.querySelectorAll('form')]
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  forms.forEach(e => {
    if (e) e.remove()
  })
})
```

```html
<form id='generalForm' method='post' action='". $url ."'>
  <input type='password' name='enterPassword' placeholder='Введите пароль от файла'>
  <input type='submit' name='sendPassword' value='Подтвердить'>
</form>

<form method='post' action='$url' id='subdivisionForm'>
  <input hidden name='shareChoose' value='$shareChoose'>
  <input hidden name='sharePath' value='$path'>
  <input hidden name='shareFilename' value='$filename'>
  <input type='submit' name='shareSubdivision' value='Поделиться'>
</form>

<form method='post' action='$url' id='loginShare'>
  <input hidden name='shareChoose' value='$shareChoose'>
  <input hidden name='sharePath' value='$path'>
  <input hidden name='shareFilename' value='$filename'>
  <input type='text' name='loginForShare' placeholder='Введите логин пользователя'>
  <input type='submit' name='shareLogin' value='Поделиться'>
</form>

<form method='post' action='$url' id='passForm'>
  <input hidden name='shareChoose' value='$shareChoose'>
  <input hidden name='sharePath' value='$path'>
  <input hidden name='shareFilename' value='$filename'>
  <input type='text' name='pass' placeholder='Введите пароль для скачивания'>
  <input type='submit' name='shareGeneral' value='Поделиться'>
</form>

<button>Remove all forms</button>
```

Comment: Я бы хотел сделать так, чтобы они удалялись именно при загрузке страницы, а не по кнопке

Comment: используйте событие document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {})